# GAE: Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html

Tags: google-app-engine, mime-types

I have a Google App Engine site, and when I use javascript to load a stylesheet (editor.css) the styles are not applied to the html and I get this error:

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html.
```

My stylesheets that are declared in the HTML do not throw this warning...only the one called via javascript in an iframe. How do I debug this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your app is sending the css file with the mimetype "text/html" instead of "text/css". Use your browser's development tools to verify this (look for the request for the CSS file and examine the response headers.

If the file is being served by application code, make sure you're sending the correct mimetype. If it's being served as a static file, you can set the mimetype as documented [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html#Static_File_Handlers).

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved by setting the Mime type configuration in the `app.yaml` of your app engine application.

```
application: your application name
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1
handlers:
- url: /stylesheets
  mime_type: 'text/css'
  static_dir: stylesheets
- url: .*
  script: helloworld.php
```

Ensure that CSS files are kept in stylesheets folder or rename the `static_dir` folder to your CSS folder.